# JOIN Files using first three alpha numeric?

Tags: t-sql, left-join

I am trying to create a JOIN Account Numbers. One file has full act# whereas other has first 2 or 3 Alpha Numeric. (These represents Countries)

Example:

file 1 -

```
136xxxxxx
802xxxxxx 
X1xxxxxxx
V1xxxxxxx
```

File 2 -

```
136
802
X1
V1
```

How can I use JOIN to match data? Kindly help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Select A.*
      ,B.*
 From  File1 A
 Join  File2 B
   on  A.KeyCol like B.KeyCol+'%'
```

Use `Left Join` if you want to see everything from File1 and potential nulls in File2